# Java 8 Collectors groupingBy reducing gives cannot resolve method error

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have some OrderTotal thats an object type containing amount and currency. I want to do total of each currency. I wrote the below code but `MoneyAmount::getAmount` gives me cannot resolve method getAmount error. I am not able to get what's wrong here and why is it not able to resolve the method.

```
List<MoneyAmount> orderTotalsByCurrency = orderTotals.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MoneyAmount::getCurrencyCode,
            Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, new BigDecimal(MoneyAmount::getAmount), BigDecimal::add)));
```

Comment: Can you paste `MoneyAmount` class?

Comment: what is the type of `MoneyAmount::getAmount` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a method reference in the constructor of [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) because it accepts neither interface matching the `m -> m.getAmount()` lambda expression (which is a [`Function<MoneyAmount, String>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html)) nor any functional interface (see the constructors).

Also, note that [`Collectors::groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) returns a `Map`, therefore the return type has to correspond with the grouping strategy. The downstream collector [`Collectors::reducing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#reducing-U-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) causes the `List<BigDecimal>` is reduced to `BigDecimal` using a mapper and an operator.

Considering the following class:

```
class MoneyAmount {

    private final BigDecimal amount;
    private final String currencyCode;

    // constructor and getters
}
```

The following Stream should do the thing:

```
final Map<String, BigDecimal> orderTotalsByCurrency = orderTotals.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        MoneyAmount::getCurrencyCode,    // String currencyCode is the key
        Collectors.reducing(             // Reducing value List<BigDecimal> to BigDecimal
            BigDecimal.ZERO,             // Identity
            MoneyAmount::getAmount,      // Mapper (geting the amount to sum)
            BigDecimal::add)));          // Operator (action to 2 subsequent values)
```

In case the `amount` is not `BigDecimal` but `String` which shall be used as the way to construct the `BigDecimal`, then change the downstream line with method reference `MoneyAmount` to :

```
Collectors.reducing(
    BigDecimal.ZERO, 
    m -> new BigDecimal(m.getAmount()),  // Here, BigDecimal from String
    BigDecimal::add)));
```

Comment: Thanks this did the trick. My amount is String so conversion to BigDecimal worked!

Comment: Glad it works. You are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

you are grouping by so you return value won't be a list it's `Map<String,BigDecimal>` assuming currencyCode is String

```
Map<String, BigDecimal> collect = orderTotals.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MoneyAmount::getCurrencyCode,
                        Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, m -> new BigDecimal(m.getAmount()), BigDecimal::add)));
```

```
collect.forEach((k,v) -> System.out.println(k+"-"+v)); //outputs the total sum of each currency
```